# Django admin - list_editable - foreign key attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.10

Is it possible to make editable `ForeignKey` attribute in change list?

Every user has it's `UserProfile` object (`OneToOneField`). I want admin to be able to modify `UserProfile` expiry date from `User` change list.

I can display the `expiry` in change list:

```
class UserCustomAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'username','email', 'last_login','userprofile__expiracia']
    # list_editable = ['userprofile__expiracia']
    exclude = ['groups','user_permissions']
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       )}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    def userprofile__expiracia(self,obj):
        return obj.userprofile.expiracia
```

But I can't add `userprofile__expiracia` to `list_editable` list. It raises:

```
<class 'dashboard.admin.UserCustomAdmin'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to 'userprofile__expiracia', which is not an attribute of 'auth.User'.
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You can probably overwrite the method that `list_editable` uses to actually update the object(s).